# How to create a SAF file for virus sequence?

Tags: r, bioconductor, covid-19, rna, virus

I am trying to create a SAF file for the virus sequence. I can download .gff3 and .gb format for the virus gene sequence but they are not supported by **featureCounts**. I need to create my own SAF. I tried making one but I am confused about the GeneID and Chr. The manual says Chr should match Chromosome number in the BAM or SAM file generated by **align** function. But viruses don't have chromosome. Could anybody help me with this please?

Here is the link of the virus sequence which I am trying to create a SAF table for.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY386263.1

---

Quoted from [R documentation website](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rsubread/versions/1.22.2/topics/featureCounts)
**featureCounts** is a general-purpose read summarization function, which assigns to the genomic features (or meta-features) the mapped reads that were generated from genomic DNA and RNA sequencing.
... Both SAM and BAM format input files are accepted.

...paraphrasing
There is an in-built annotation that uses SAF format however `annot.ext` will override this for a custom SAF file.

Comment: According to the [featureCounts documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rsubread/versions/1.22.2/topics/featureCounts): "Users may also provide a GTF/GFF format annotation via annot.ext argument. But GTF/GFF annotation should only be provided as a file, and isGTFAnnotationFile should be set to TRUE when such a annotation is provided."

Comment: Cross-post here https://www.biostars.org/p/318489/